# Is there a way to disable the sonarqube ldap plugin email synchronization?

Tags: plugins, ldap, sonarqube

Currently we are using ldap plugin (version 2.1.0.507) for our Sonarqube (version 5.6.1) user authentication but our ldap is not configured for email. Thus every time we add an email locally for notifications it is wiped away when you log out via the ldap sync. Is there a way to disable the sync so that our locally configured emails remain?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not possible. [LDAP Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) **fully** delegates authentication, as well as synchronization of usernames and emails (+ groups if *Group Mapping* is configured).

No workaround, your best shot here really is to propagate email addresses in your LDAP server (which seems like a fair expectation for a user directory).